# how to dynamically update embedded document with $set in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to create a function that changes the value of an embedded MongoDB document (contained in an array) with a given position.

```
removeAddress(accountNumber, position) {
    const remove = Account.findOneAndUpdate({ accountNumber: accountNumber }, { $set: { `mailingAddress.${position}.active`: false } })

    return Promise.resolve(remove);
}
```

Iv tried using es6 string interpolation `mailingAddress.${position}.active`  and `"mailingAddress." + position + ".active"` but neither work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the setter dynamically :

```
var setter = { $set: {} };
setter.$set["mailingAddress." + position + ".active"] = false;

const remove = Account.findOneAndUpdate({
    accountNumber: accountNumber
}, setter)
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Thanks.